# Dynamically creating a new column and sorting by that column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of prices of items from various dates in the past. Here's basically what I have:

```
Item      Price   Date
----------------------------
Item 1    1.83    04-06
Item 1    1.56    04-07
Item 2    2.37    04-06
Item 2    2.94    04-07
Item 3    0.68    04-06
Item 3    0.54    04-07
```

I want to sort the items by their change in price. I don't know how to approach this using MySQL, is this even possible using just MySQL?

Comment: Change in price relative to other rows?

Comment: Change in price of an item relative to the price of the same item from the previous date.

Comment: What would the change be for the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your table is named `Items`. Something like this?

```
SELECT t1.Price - t2.Price as PriceDiff, t2.* 
FROM Items as t1, Items as t2 
WHERE TO_DAYS(t1.Date) - TO_DAYS(t2.Date) = 1 AND t1.Item = t2.Item 
ORDER BY PriceDiff ASC
```

The key is the following which matches the items according to their Item name and the Item from the previous day... you may need to change your Date column to a datetime, not sure of its current type.

```
TO_DAYS(t1.date) - TO_DAYS(t2.date) = 1 AND t1.Item = t2.Item
```

If you wanted price changes only from a specific day, then add `AND Date = 'yourdate'`

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Andy has said, in general, you each time you want to compare a table against itself (ie some function between two rows in the same table) you will need a join for each variable in the function.

```
SELECT i1.price as 'i1', i2.price as 'i2', i1.price-i2.price as priceDiff, i1.id
FROM itemPrice i1
JOIN itemPrice i2 on i1.id = i2.id
WHERE DATE_ADD(i1.pdate, INTERVAL -1 DAY) = i2.pdate
ORDER BY PRICEDIFF desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eec6/4

Answer (score 0):

following sql should do

```
SELECT Item, MAX(Price) - MIN(Price) as PriceDiff
FROM Table
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY MAX(Price) - MIN(Price)
```